# Get the li value if the mouse pointer passes over it with mousedown using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swipe

I'm working on a virtual keyboard which would work same as the on-screen keyboard in windows.

**Question:** I'm looking to add the functionality of a **swype** keyboard, where the user enters words by dragging from the 
first letter of a word to its last letter using mouse. Is it possible to achieve this with a mouse?

**Problem:** I have tried this with jQuery `swipe` event so far where I have multiple `li` as keys and while dragging from a key 
to another the text of a single `li` element is what I'm getting.

How to get all the key values where ever the mouse pointer passes by while dragging, something like this from Android swype keyboard?

[image]

Check this [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/c2pvmxc7/3/)

```
$("li").on("swipe", function() {
    $('#input').append($(this).text());
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").on("swipe", function() {
        $('#input').append($(this).text());
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font: 71%/1.5 Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    background: #eee;
}
#container {
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 688px;
}
#write {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 671px;
    height: 200px;
    font: 1em/1.5 Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
#keyboard {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
#keyboard li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #777;
    color: #eaeaea;
    border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.capslock,
.tab,
.left-shift {
    clear: left;
}
#keyboard .tab,
#keyboard .delete {
    width: 70px;
}
#keyboard .capslock {
    width: 80px;
}
#keyboard .return {
    width: 77px;
}
#keyboard .left-shift {
    width: 95px;
}
#keyboard .right-shift {
    width: 109px;
}
.lastitem {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#keyboard .space {
    clear: left;
    width: 681px;
}
.on {
    display: none;
}
#keyboard li:hover {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    border-color: #e5e5e5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li p {
    display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div id="container">
    <textarea id="input" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
    <ul id="keyboard">
    <li class="symbol"><p>`</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p>1</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p>2</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p>3</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p>4</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p>5</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p>6</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p>7</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p>8</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p>9</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p>0</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p>-</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p>=</p></li>
        <li class="delete lastitem"><p>delete</p></li>
        <li class="tab"><p>tab</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>q</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>w</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>e</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>r</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>t</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>y</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>u</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>i</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>o</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>p</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p><span class="off">[</span><span class="on">{</span></p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p><span class="off">]</span><span class="on">}</span></p></li>
        <li class="symbol lastitem"><p><span class="off">\</span><span class="on">|</span></p></li>
        <li class="capslock"><p>caps lock</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>a</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>s</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>d</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>f</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>g</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>h</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>j</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>k</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>l</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p><span class="off">;</span><span class="on">:</span></p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p><span class="off">'</span><span class="on">&quot;</span></p></li>
        <li class="return lastitem"><p>return</p></li>
        <li class="left-shift"><p>shift</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>z</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>x</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>c</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>v</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>b</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>n</p></li>
        <li class="letter"><p>m</p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p><span class="off">,</span><span class="on">&lt;</span></p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p><span class="off">.</span><span class="on">&gt;</span></p></li>
        <li class="symbol"><p><span class="off">/</span><span class="on">?</span></p></li>
        <li class="right-shift lastitem"><p>shift</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by sliding?

Comment: I mean dragging

Comment: like dragging a letter in the input box?

Comment: i need all the key values whereever the pointer passes by

Comment: like a hover effect you mean?

Comment: No, i want the key values as a whole word. please check my updated question.

Comment: why not use drag  events? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use the hover function of jQuery along with tracking the state of the mouse down button it works.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mouseDown = 0;
    document.body.onmousedown = function() { 
        mouseDown = 1;
    }
    document.body.onmouseup = function() {
        mouseDown = 0;
    }

    $("li").hover(function() {
        if (mouseDown) {
            $('#input').append($(this).text());
        }
    }, function() {
      // do nothing
    });

    $("li").on("mousedown", function() {
        $('#input').append($(this).text());
    });
});
```

What I am doing here is checking when a "li" element gets hovered, and if the mouse button is down, add it to the input.

Also note the last bit, that is for when the mouse goes down on a "li" element for the first time. (Since you hover the first button you want to start swiping one before clicking with the mouse. This prevents us from missing the first letter of the swipe sequence.)

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bLt0j5t9/1/

Comment: This is cool but not accurate :) However I could find a way out with this. Appreciate your help!